# radGrid control not showing data in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, updatepanel, radgrid

I have an asp.net application (created by a previous developer) that uses a RadGrid control to display data. However, the RadGrid does not show data if there is an  on the page. The radGrid works fine soon as I remove the UpdatePanel. If I remove the Updatepanel, then RadCombobox makes a whole page submit (instead of using Ajax).

Is there anyway to make radGrid and  work together?

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlFilter" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <span class="subHeader">VTRIP Log Search:  </span>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderColor="#E3B391" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                BorderWidth="1" Width="994px">
                <div style="height:10px; width:994px">
                </div>                  
                    <table style="width: 974px; margin: 10px" border="0">                                          
                    <tr>
                        <td width="200px">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="DriverDD" runat="server" Height="120px" Width="180px"
                                DropDownWidth="180px" EmptyMessage="Choose a Driver" 
                                HighlightTemplatedItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                onselectedindexchanged="DriverDD_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </td>

                        <td width="220px">
                            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDOS"
                                WatermarkText="Select today or any previous day" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
                            </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOS" runat="server" Width="200px" EnableViewState="true" CssClass="SetTextbox"
                                Height="20px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDOS_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
                                TargetControlID="txtDOS">
                            </asp:CalendarExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:350px">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>   

    <br/>   
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" OnSortCommand="RadGrid1_SortCommand" 
OnPageIndexChanged="RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged"
            Width="99%" Height="181px" OnPageSizeChanged="RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged" AllowSorting="True"
            PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" runat="server"
            GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <MasterTableView Height="100px" Width="100%" Summary="RadGrid table">
                <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
                <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" 
                    Visible="True">
                </RowIndicatorColumn>
                <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" 
                    Visible="True">
                </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TripId" HeaderText="Trip ID" SortExpression="TripID"
                        UniqueName="TripID"  
                        SortAscImageUrl="SortAsc.gif" SortDescImageUrl="SortDesc.gif">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MemberName" HeaderText="Member Name" SortExpression="MemberName"
                        UniqueName="MemberName"  
                        SortAscImageUrl="SortAsc.gif" SortDescImageUrl="SortDesc.gif">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="VehicleType" HeaderText="Vehicle Type" SortExpression="VehicleType"
                        UniqueName="VehicleType"
                        SortAscImageUrl="SortAsc.gif" SortDescImageUrl="SortDesc.gif">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status"
                        UniqueName="Status"  
                        SortAscImageUrl="SortAsc.gif" SortDescImageUrl="SortDesc.gif">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
                <EditFormSettings>
                    <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                    </EditColumn>
                </EditFormSettings>
                <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
            </MasterTableView>
            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>
            <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
            </FilterMenu>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Code behind: (populate grid using [Grid - Simple Data Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/simplebinding/defaultcs.aspx))

```
private void LoadData()
{
    if (Session["TripMaster"] != null)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = Session["TripMaster"];
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate the data to RadGrid? Could you post the code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you move `RadGrid` inside `UpdatePanel` and try it again?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlFilter" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <span class="subHeader">VTRIP Log Search:  </span>
     <asp:Panel 
        ....
     </asp:Panel>
    <br/>   
    <telerik:RadGrid
      ....
    </telerik:RadGrid>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Could you remove `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and try it again?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [RadAjaxManager](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/ajax.aspx) to run through this operation for you, and you will not see a full postback and rendering of all items in the AjaxPanel.  We recommend this approach as it results in less controls on the page and a more targeted update of your controls.

Remove the UpdatePanels and add the [RadAjaxManager](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/ajax.aspx) to your page with markup like this:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="ajaxMgr">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="DriverDD">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

... and you should see the same results, with less markup and events to worry about.

Finally, if you are using the 2013 Q1 [AJAX controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx), I suggest you change your RadComboBox to a [RadDropDownList](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).  This control has significantly less markup when you are providing a standard combobox.  Another option to lighten your generated HTML from this control would be to add the `RenderMode="Lightweight"` attribute to have it generate a smaller HTML footprint that modern browsers support.

Comment: That is great info, @Jeff. I will try that out and let you know. Thanks. Though my opinion, Telerik needs to do a better job of documentation and responding on support forums.

Comment: Are you referring to Stackoverflow, or the Telerik support forums?  Depending on your support contract, you will get different SLA response times on the forums.  Stackoverflow is NOT tracked like the Telerik forums  All of that information is tracked internally

Comment: Stackoverflow has spoiled me into expecting a response within 60 seconds. Telerik tends to respond 5 days later, which, in my world, is way too long inorder to deliver a project on time. Will check on my SLA.

Comment: Telerik license holders will get a response to support tickets in 24h for free.  Do you have a link to the prior forum post with a 5-day turnaround?  Let's take this to email - jeff.fritz@telerik.com and I'll follow-up to ensure you are getting the support you need.